# Strange behavior of str.len() for empty set

Tags: python, pandas

I am experiencing a strange behavior on counting elements in column of sets with [pd.Series.str.len()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) method

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['', 'A', 'A B', 'A B C']})
x['s'] = x.t.str.split(' ').map(set)
x['s_len'] = x.s.str.len()
x['s_reduced'] = x.s - {'A'}
x['s_reduced_len'] = x.s_reduced.str.len()
print(x)

    t       s           s_len   s_reduced   s_reduced_len
0           {}          1       {}          1
1   A       {A}         1       {}          0
2   A B     {B, A}      2       {B}         1
3   A B C   {C, B, A}   3       {C, B}      2
```

Why in this case the value of `x.loc[0, 's_len']` is 1 and the value of `x.loc[1, 's_reduced_len']` is 0?

Is it a bug and I should report it or is it an odd intended behavior?

The version of pandas is 0.20.3.

Comment: I don't understand your question? You are accessing _completely different cells_.

Comment: Well you use `str` again...

Comment: @COLDSPEED Both `x.loc[0, 's_len']` and `x.loc[1, 's_reduced_len']` ought be the result of evaluating the lengths of empty set. In one case the result is 0, in another it's 1. My question is why is that.

Comment: Huh, I see the problem now. Yeah, a set with an empty string counts as a non-empty set indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the answer if you just print the contents i.e

```
x.s_reduced.values

array([{''}, set(), {'B'}, {'C', 'B'}], dtype=object)
```

The first cell is actaully not empty if holds `''`. And after subtraction second cell becomes an empty set. Hence the difference in lengths.

```
len({''})
1

len(set())
0
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. That was my mistake of not knowing the result of split operation and getting confused in misleading representation of strings withing a set (an empty string is not displayed and you suppose that set is empty).

Comment: It happens, a cross check of values would be necessary every time before coming to a conclusion.

Comment: Good catch ! :-)